# How to generate qrcode in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to generate  qrcode code in my application with qrgen and then saved in specific file but there is a problem in the libary 'java.io.FileOutputStream' where it can not be found. i want to know how to replace the libary and if there is another way to generate qrcode please share it with me

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream out =QRCode.from(s).to(ImageType.PNG).stream();

    try {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\QR_Code.JPG"));

        fout.write(out.toByteArray());

        fout.flush();
        fout.close();

    }  catch (Exception e) {
        // Do Logging
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't supported. Mobile devices don't have a file system in the way desktops have so this logic just won't work. There is a file system but it's to a large part private to the application, see: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html

Comment: Thank you for answer, can you help me to find another way,to generate qrcode and thank you again for your help

Comment: Use `FileSystemStorage` it lets you open an output steam and you can write to that. You can then use the share API from display to share that URL which should launch the ability to share via whatsapp, dropbox etc. when running on the device